# Custom fields in channel information?

Tags: channel

I have some channels on a site, with some of the channels making up the main navigation for the site.

Each top level navigation item needs an image, a short description, and a different title than the channel name.

Been looking for a plugin to add custom data to the channel itself, but I keep coming up short.

I might be missing an obvious way to do this, or maybe I just can't find the right module.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but i don't think there is such option in EE
The only thing you could do is go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Preference 
There you could change Full channel name and add a description but there isn't an option for image.

Perhaps [low variable](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) could be a solution in order to create a navigation + sub-navigation with different images, description and title?

Here is a list of how you could use Low Variables in different ways
http://www.blue-dreamer.co.uk/blog/entry/creative-uses-for-low-variables

Answer (score 0):

Create a channel with entries (maybe a matrix) that correspond to the channels...pull you nav from that?

Comment: Yeah, I was considering both Low Variables and the seperate channel idea.

The best would be to make a module for this, but there is no time in projects scope to do this. I think I'll do the seperate channel thing, because I think that'll prove to be the least challenging for the client.